# Apache Cxf fail when use PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, powermock

I am trying to test one component of my application which use Apache Cxf as a client to create service port. I read the documentation of Apache Cxf where is mentioned that EasyMock is preferable mock framework, but in my situation I need to use the PowerMock extension for it (I want to mock static methods and use MockPolicy). I use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean class to create service port and when run test whit EasyMockRunner everything works fine, but with PowerMockRunner the same test fails with this error.

```
Oct 31, 2016 9:27:18 AM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {urn:... from class defpack.MyService
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:388)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:469)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:696)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:529)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
```

Any ideas how to fix or workaround it ?

Comment: try to add `org.apache.cxf` to `@PowerMockIgnore`

Comment: Thank you @ArthurZagretdinov , but in one of my tests I need to check the soap message, so I don't have to ignore cxf